# Exceptions from routes using parallel processing

Tags: apache-camel

I have three "levels" of routes:

- direct:start is a simple route that "calls" direct:middle
- direct:middle has multicast/parallelProcessing, calling two others
- the two other routes (at the third level) both throw exceptions

This sample forces those two lowest-level routes to throw exceptions.
When coded as below, I see two exception (printed as shown in the *onException*() )

```
public void configure() throws Exception {

onException().handled(true).log(" ---------------   Exception!!  -------------------------");

from("direct:start")
 .log("Actual start ")
 .inOut("direct:middle")
 .log(" ---------------   Caught Exception -------------------------")
 .log("Actual End ");


from("direct:middle")
//.errorHandler(noErrorHandler())
.log("after direct:start body=${body}")
.multicast(new MyAggregationStrategy()).parallelProcessing().stopOnException()
  .to("direct:A")
  .to("direct:B")
.end();

from("direct:A").errorHandler(noErrorHandler()).process(new ExceptionThrower());
from("direct:B").errorHandler(noErrorHandler()).process(new ExceptionThrower());
```

}

I **UN**-commented the *noErrorHandler()* in "direct:middle" thinking that it might still run the onException(), but only give a single exception. 
Instead, it acted as if there was no onException() specified in the RouteBuilder, throwing the Exception all the way back to the caller.

I'm interested in understanding why it does that. 
I tried using doTry() ... doCatch() in the outermost route, and that seemed to work, but I'm not sure why the other approach does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.
I ended up to the same conclusions as you (a few years ago, but I do not think it has changed). Actually, the error/exception handling (not to say propagation) is IMHO *the* most (may be powerful but yet) confusing thing in Camel.

According to the doc, specifying no error handler in a route will make your route implicitly use the `DefaultErrorHandler` whose behaviour is:

> By default, any exception thrown during routing will be propagated
>   back to the caller and the Exchange ends immediately

That's true..as long as you stay in the same route !
If you want to propagate the exception in a subroute ("direct:middle") back to the calling route ("direct:start"), you indeed **HAVE** to introduce a:

```
.errorHandler(noErrorHandler() )
```

Now for the multicast/split/recipientList EIP, do not forget these are working on **copies** of the original Exchange. Any error on a copy does not affect the "master" exchange. If you need this functionality, activate the "shareUnitOfWork" (or implement a smart aggregationStrategy that aggregate potential exceptions on sub-exchanges into a unique exception)

Comment: The thing is, when I add  errorHandler(noErrorHandler() ) to "direct:middle" it does propagate upward, but: I would have expected it to do the error-handling as defined in the onException()... at the RouteBuilder level. I'm curious why it skips doing that. Instead, it throws the exception all the way back to the place that trigger the outermost route.